# Google BigQuery: I see that "clientId" column is missing, but is actually present in the table's schema

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Google BigQuery: when working with UNION ALL my query threw an error:
"Queries in UNION ALL have mismatched column count; query 1 has 17 columns, query 2 has 18 columns"

When I individually run the queries, I see that "clientId" column is missing, but is actually present in the table. Please find the query below.

How is it possible, that with analytics schema, the column is present in one dataset.table and not in another?

How can I fix this issue?

````
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        'web' AS platform
        ,a.*
        ,a._TABLE_SUFFIX AS TABLE_SUFFIX
        from `[project].[dataset for Web].ga_sessions_*` a        
     where 
      _table_suffix BETWEEN  '20190401' AND '20190401'
    ) web
UNION ALL
SELECT android.*
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        'android' AS platform
        ,a.*
        ,a._TABLE_SUFFIX AS TABLE_SUFFIX
        from `[project].[dataset for Android].ga_sessions_*` a   
     where 
       _table_suffix BETWEEN  '20190401' AND '20190401'
    ) android```
````

Comment: This happened after we migrated the tables to EU location, When we do the same in old tables, there is no issues!

Comment: See if this helps: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#schema_used_for_query_evaluation

Answer (score 0):

Taking your query as base, I ran the following query, which it was executed properly:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    'web' AS platform,
    a.*,
    a._TABLE_SUFFIX AS TABLE_SUFFIX
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*` a
  WHERE
    _table_suffix BETWEEN '20170801' AND '20170801'
  LIMIT 5) web
UNION ALL
SELECT
  android.*
FROM (
  SELECT
    'android' AS platform,
    a.*,
    a._TABLE_SUFFIX AS TABLE_SUFFIX
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*` a
  WHERE
    _table_suffix BETWEEN '20170801' AND '20170801'
  LIMIT 5) android
```

Considering the error message that you are obtaining, the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#schema_used_for_query_evaluation) in the comments, and the dataset migration, seems that the [migrated dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations#moving-data) is incomplete.

Maybe trying a new dataset migration might help to mitigate the incomplete information, considering the [BigQuery export schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719) over the destination table.

Since I have not enough reputation, this is the reason for posting this answer.